# I can't find the bug in this implementation of backpropogation?

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation

My data is 4123 rows of inputs and outputs to an xor gate.
I want to write a Neural Network with three input layer neurons (the third one is bias), a hidden layer, and an output layer.

Here's my implementation

```
import numpy as np

class TwoLayerNetwork:
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        """
            input_size:  the number of neurons in the input layer
            hidden_size: the number of neurons in the hidden layer
            output_size: the number of neurons in the output layer
        """
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.output_size = output_size

        self.params = {}
        self.params['W1'] = 0.01 * np.random.randn(input_size, hidden_size)  # FxH
        self.params['b1'] = np.zeros((hidden_size, 1)) # Hx1
        self.params['W2'] = 0.01 * np.random.randn(hidden_size, output_size)  # HxO
        self.params['b2'] = np.zeros((output_size, 1))  # Ox1

        self.optimal_weights = []
        self.errors = {}

    def train(self, X, y, epochs):
        """
            X: input data matrix, NxF
            y: output vector, Nx1

            returns:
               the optimal set of parameters that best minimize the loss function
        """

        W1, b1 = self.params['W1'], self.params['b1']
        W2, b2 = self.params['W2'], self.params['b2']



        for iteration in range(epochs):


            forward_to_hidden = X.dot(W1)  # NxH
            activate_hidden = sigmoid(forward_to_hidden)  # NxH
            forward_to_output = activate_hidden.dot(W2)  # NxO
            output = sigmoid(forward_to_output)  # NxO

            self.errors[iteration] = np.mean(0.5 * (y**2 - output**2))

            output_error = y - output  # NxO

            output_layer_delta = output_error * sigmoidPrime(output)  # NxO
            hidden_layer_error = output_layer_delta.dot(W2.T)  # NxO . OxH = NxH
            hidden_layer_delta = hidden_layer_error * sigmoidPrime(activate_hidden) # NxH

            W1_update = X.T.dot(hidden_layer_delta)  # FxN . NxH = FxH
            W2_update = activate_hidden.T.dot(output_layer_delta)  # HxN . NxO = HxO

            W1 += W1_update
            W2 += W2_update

        self.optimal_weights.append(W1)
        self.optimal_weights.append(W2)


    def predict(self, X):
        W1, W2 = self.optimal_weights[0], self.optimal_weights[1]

        forward = sigmoid(X.dot(W1))  # NxH
        forward = forward.dot(W2)  # NxO
        forward = sigmoid(forward) # NxO

        return forward



def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
def sigmoidPrime(x):
    return sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x))
```

I realize that's very vanilla, but that's intentional. I want to understand the most basic form of NN architecture first.

Now, my problem is that my error plot is confusing.

[image]

The neural network just stops learning.

My second problem is that my weights are blowing up reaching up to -10000, which causes overflow because of exp in the sigmoid function.

My third problem is that my output vector only outputs 0.5 instead of 1 or 0

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('xor.csv').sample(frac=1)
X = data.iloc[:, [0, 1]]  # 1st and 2nd cols are the input
X = np.hstack((X, np.ones((data.shape[0], 1))))  # adding the bias 1's
y = data.iloc[:, 2][:, np.newaxis]  # 3rd col is the output

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25)

nn.train(X_train, y_train, 100)

plt.plot(range(100), [i for i in nn.errors.values()])
plt.show()
```

[The link for the dataset](https://github.com/MustafaAdam/random-machine-learning-python-code/blob/master/xor.csv)

Comment: updated answer, should be going strong now

Answer (score 0):

So, if I read your code correctly, your network is specified correctly, but is missing a few key points in order to learn XOR by backpropagation.

The fun part is, your error specification is weird.
I made it into
`self.errors[iteration] = np.mean(0.5 * (y - output)**2)`
for visualization.
With x-axis denoting epoch and y-axis denoting error:
[image]

So what happens, the backpropagation hits a plateau, then rapidly blows up the weights. To slow down the blowing up of the weights and allow the network some time to re-evaluate its mistakes, you can add a so-called "learning rate" != 1. This adresses one of the pitfalls.

Another one is the second figure: you hit oscillatory behaviour in the updates and the program will never reach its optimum state. To adress this, you can deliberately enter an imperfection in the form of a "momentum".
[image]

Additionally, the initial conditions matter for the speed at which you converge, so you need to have enough epochs to overcome the local plateaux:

[image]

Last, but certainly not least, I did find an error with your specification, but all of the above still applies.

In your layer_deltas you do sigmoidPrime(sigmoid(forwards)) which is one call to sigmoid too many.

```
last_update = np.zeros((X.shape[1], W1.shape[1]))
last_update2 = np.zeros((W1.shape[1], W2.shape[1]))
        output_layer_delta = output_error * sigmoidPrime(forward_to_output)  # NxO
        hidden_layer_delta = hidden_layer_error * sigmoidPrime(forward_to_hidden) # NxH

        W1 += 0.001*(W1_update + last_update * 0.5)
        W2 += 0.001*(W2_update + last_update2 * 0.5)
#            W1 = 0.001*W1_update
#            W2 = 0.001*W2_update
        last_update = W1_update.copy()
        last_update2 = W2_update.copy()
```

Did the final trick for me. Now please verify and appease this grumbling man who spent the better part of a night and day on figuring it out. ;)

Comment: tried that. I thought two output neurons will give one neuron a high probability and the other one a low one, then maybe I can threshold. But all I got was 0.5 for both neurons

Comment: I don't even know if the output for both neurons is going to be technically a probability.

Comment: hmm..the network does not seem too badly specified for the rest of it..it misses some efficient backpropagation techniques, but as you said, you went for basics..I literally copied your network and tested it on some mnist data, 100 training epochs and 81% accuracy, no problem. I really think it has to do with your input-output format. Think it's already nice to know the network itself is not buggy. :)

Comment: 81% !!! you're kidding me. Wow I am genuinely impressed by this. You might be right it's the data. Can you please try on this csv file?

Comment: I've added a bias column to the input data and a neuron in the input layer.

Comment: A question: Could it be the biases? I've added a bias neuron and column, however my code is ignoring the biases completely?

Comment: That is very well possible, but I will refrain from conclusive statements until I have been able to play around a bit. (p.s. I do not see the csv yet)

Comment: Sorry about that :). I've added it to the original post.

Comment: okay.. If I read it using the pd.read_csv().sample(frac=1) style, I get a really weird dataframe. Can you check for me yours does read normally?

Comment: It does work. I get a regular dataframe. The column names are ['1.000000000000000000e+00', '0.000000000000000000e+00',  '1.000000000000000000e+00.1'], but other than, it's all good as far as I can see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151649/discussion-between-uvar-and-maa).

Comment: Thanks for your persistence on solving this Uvar. I've added momentum and a learning rate just as you said. It did not work properly until I've reduced the learning rate to 0.01 and increased the epochs to around 500. This is when I got a 0.01% training error rate. Which I think is great. However, I still cannot classify the testing set because I get the same score for both output neurons/classes.

Comment: And it predicts all 0's for MNIST data set with an overflow error in the sigmoid function. https://github.com/MustafaAdam/Basics-of-Machine-Learning/blob/master/Neural_Networks/TwoLayerNet.ipynb

Comment: NN = TwoLayerNetwork(3, 2, 1) is what I used in this case for the XOR gate. In principle, with your 2 outputs being completely the same in this case, but with a distinction; I guess you can hackily classify based on the mean output of the 2? What goes wrong in any case, is that the data supplied is not rich enough to classify to 2 outputs. You only train on one-dimensional y_train! :)

Comment: As to MNIST, as you decrease learning rate, you will require more steps to train. Using a small amount of training steps, I ran into the same problem, uniform predictions (in my case, 1); but! increasing my epochs to 10.000 I got 90% accuracy once again. :)